# WooCommerce Product Filtering with AJAX

Tags: ajax, filtering, woocommerce

I am trying to understand where the functionality for Woocommerce resides that handles AJAX requests on the Product Archive Pages. So for example when you use the Select Dropdown Form on the Shop page, or when you add a Woocommerce Sidebar Widget like the Layered Nav, or the Product Categories widget. Which WC file either PHP and or Jquery is handling the AJAX request and then returning the Sorted/Filtered data back to the page.

Ultimately what I am trying to do is hook into the default woocommerce AJAX functionality so I can extend it to fade in each product list item `<li>` separately, or any number of CSS3 effects, like transform 3D. As well as adding a switch button that toggles between Grid and List views for product category pages.

But I just can't find where in the Woocommerce files this is happening.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know the basic WooCommerce plugin does not provide AJAX ability for Product Archive Pages.

If you like to add Ajax filtering and Ajax reload of Product Archive page you can use:

a) WooCommerce commercial plugin:
http://www.woothemes.com/products/ajax-layered-navigation/

b) Free WordPress plugin called 'YITH WooCommerce Ajax Navigation':
http://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-ajax-navigation/

c) WooCommerce AJAX Product Filter plugin:
http://codenegar.com/woocommerce-ajax-product-filter/

or something similar.

Comment: All of these plugin not actually AJAX, it just load whole page and using Javascript select needed parts. Therefore it has the same speed with when you load the whole page. Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

WOOF: https://www.woocommerce-filter.com , appeared in 2015 year, AJAX is there as a lot of another tasty features